# RunListener result method

Tags: java, junit

I have a class who extends RunListener.

I would like to know the result of the method.
So in this method :

```
public void testFinished(Description description) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println("Finished execution of test case : " + description.getMethodName());
}
```

I would like something like : description.getResult(), but it doesn't existe.
How can I make ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever methods you can use depends on the `Description` object. If you want/need `getResult()`, you will have to implement that method in the `Description` class and make it public.

**Example:**

This is an example of the method you need to implement in your `Description` class.

```
public Object getResult() {
  // this is the method you need to implement, with whatever return type you need instead of Object (String etc.)
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I have a problem to redefine the constructor :

 public MyDescription(Class<?> fTestClass, String fDisplayName, Annotation fAnnotations) {
  super(fTestClass, fDisplayName, fAnnotations);
 }

There is a message :

> The constructor Description(Class<?>, String, Annotation...) is not visible

Are you sure your solution is correct ?

Comment: You don't need to redefine the constructor, this was just an example. Only implement the `getResult()` method, and other variables/methods if required only.